# how combine two observable and use first Observable return value

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I have two Observable  , the second Observable(convertScore$) need use return value  from first Observable (displayScore$) .

I use do operator that can be combine two main Observerbles, but second do operator(function:fakeImgSrcFromHttp) inside the first Observable(displayScore$) can't excute , Why??

---

I expected the result is：

- covert score: **100** To OtherData
- bind ImgSrc to HtmlTag: **it's a src string**
- display score: **100**
- complete

this is my code , or [you can view it from JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/zuhuxeruxi/edit?js,console)

```js
/***** From A Service *****/
var convertScore$ = fakeScoreFromHttp()
              .do(score => covertScoreToOtherData(score))
              .do(score => {
                fakeImgSrcFromHttp(score)
                .do(imgSrc => {
                  console.log("bind ImgSrc to HtmlTag:" + imgSrc);
                })
              });

function fakeScoreFromHttp(){
  return Rx.Observable.of(100);
}

function fakeImgSrcFromHttp(score){
  // ToDo : if score is something, then do else do....
  
  // return
  return Rx.Observable.of("it's a src string");
}

function covertScoreToOtherData(score){
  console.log("covert score:" + score + " To OtherData")
}

/***** From B Service *****/
var displayScore$ = convertScore$.do(score => displayScore(score));
                
displayScore$.subscribe({
    // next: (value) => { },
    // error: (err) => { console.log('Error: ' + err); },
    complete: (score) => { 
      console.log('complete'); 
    }
});

function displayScore(score){
  console.log("display score:"+score);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.1/Rx.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the operator -  flatMap

```
var example = fakeScoreFromHttp()
          .do(score => covertScoreToOtherData(score))
          .flatMap(score => {
          return  fakeImgSrcFromHttp(score)
            .do(imgSrc => {
              console.log(imgSrc);
            })
          });

example.subscribe({
// next: (value) => { console.log(value); },
// error: (err) => { console.log('Error: ' + err); },
// complete: () => { console.log('complete'); }
});


function fakeScoreFromHttp(){
return Rx.Observable.of(100);
}

function fakeImgSrcFromHttp(score){
  // ToDo : if score is something, then do else do....

 // return
return Rx.Observable.of("it's a src string");
}

function covertScoreToOtherData(score){
 console.log("covert score:" + score + " To OtherData")
}
```

Comment: you are right , but I'm sorry for my quentions is forget to add some code , I would like to ask is how to combine two Observable and the second Observable can use first Observable return value . So I update my code , very sorry , can you help me again ?

Comment: @ChunbinLi   the answer is almost the same   `var convertScore$ = fakeScoreFromHttp()
              .do(score => covertScoreToOtherData(score))
              .flatMap(score => {
              return  fakeImgSrcFromHttp(score)
                .do(imgSrc => {
                  console.log("bind ImgSrc to HtmlTag:" + imgSrc);
                })
              });`

Answer (score 0):

```js
/***** From A Service *****/
var convertScore$ = fakeScoreFromHttp()
              .do(score => covertScoreToOtherData(score))
              .flatMap(score => {
               return fakeImgSrcFromHttp(score)
                .do(imgSrc => {
                  console.log("bind ImgSrc to HtmlTag:" + imgSrc);
                })
              });

function fakeScoreFromHttp(){
  return Rx.Observable.of(100);
}

function fakeImgSrcFromHttp(score){
  // ToDo : if score is something, then do else do....
  
  // return
  return Rx.Observable.of("it's a src string");
}

function covertScoreToOtherData(score){
  console.log("covert score:" + score + " To OtherData")
}

/***** From B Service *****/
var displayScore$ = convertScore$.do(score => displayScore(score));
                
displayScore$.subscribe({
    // next: (value) => { },
    // error: (err) => { console.log('Error: ' + err); },
    complete: (score) => { 
      console.log('complete'); 
    }
});

function displayScore(score){
  console.log("display score:"+score);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.1/Rx.js"></script>
```

Comment: sorry , I think my quention is not clear enough , I hope the third expected result is 「display score:100」,but when I use flatMap it will become 「display score:it's a src string」, and I have updated the expected result in my question , I need your advice with it ,thank you